# Transferring variables $_get to another page

Tags: php

I need to send **/files/pvtexp.php?mid=162664&iid=410046&idat=2008/09&sec=2** over to page set.html so I can retrieve the info. I'm trying to get this to work am i missing something?

**Page 1:**

```
<?php
$uid = "1500"
$sndlnk = "/files/pvtexp.php?mid=162664&iid=410046&idat=2008/09&sec=2";
?>

<a href="set.html?lnk=$sndlnk&user=$uid"> Send to set.html </a>
```

**Page 2 (set.html):**

```
<?php
$lnk = $_GET['lnk'];
$user = $_GET['uid'];
echo $lnk ."\n";
echo $user ."\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you are missing a semicolon.

Should be
`$uid = "1500";`

then include the link in your php using an echo statement like so

`echo ('<a href="set.php?lnk='.urlencode($sndlnk).'&user='.urlencode($uid).'">Send to set.html </a>');`

Answer (score 2):

You need to `urlencode()` `$sndlink`.

Also, your page is `set.html`. Have you set up `html` files to be parsed with PHP?

You could also try this...

```
<?php
$params = http_build_query(array(
   'lnk' => '/files/pvtexp.php?mid=162664&iid=410046&idat=2008/09&sec=2'
   'user' => '1500'
), '', '&amp;');
?>

<a href="set.html?<?php echo $params; ?>"> Send to set.html </a>
```

Comment: Beat me to http_build_query :D

Comment: php.net says the following: The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already decoded. Using urldecode() on an element in $_GET or $_REQUEST could have unexpected and dangerous results.

how do I decode the string then? do i just do the standard $_GET?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do

```
<a href="set.html?lnk=<?php echo urlencode($sndlnk); ?>&user=<?php echo $uid; ?>"> Send to set.html </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the variable `$sndlnk` before sending through the url:

```
<?php
$uid = "1500"
$sndlnk = urlencode("/files/pvtexp.php?mid=162664&iid=410046&idat=2008/09&sec=2");
?>

<a href="set.html?lnk=$sndlnk&user=$uid"> Send to set.html </a>
```

At the second page just decode the string:

```
<?php
$lnk = urldecode($_GET['lnk']);
$user = $_GET['uid'];
echo $lnk ."\n";
echo $user ."\n";
?>
```

Ok?

Answer (score 1):

In your Page 1example, you're setting query parameters of `lnk` and `user`

```
<a href="set.html?lnk=$sndlnk&user=$uid"> Send to set.html </a>
                  ^^^         ^^^^
```

but in your Page 2 PHP, you're retrieving `lnk` and `uid` instead.

```
$lnk = $_GET['lnk'];
              ^^^
$user = $_GET['uid'];
               ^^^
```

Since there's no 'uid' in your Page 1 link, $user will come out blank. Change the `uid` to `user` on page 1 and things should work a bit better